# Magento 2 How can i make the default menu into mega menu by customising topmenu.php

Tags: magento2, megamenu

As a new Magento developer. Every day I face new problems the problem I faced today is creating my own mega menu and I find it very difficult. As I can use the extension but I don't like the idea of using the extension. So I decided to customise and create a mega menu. so I researched and read this [thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71723/how-to-create-mega-menu-in-magento) but I couldn't find my answer besides a provided link is not working anymore. so I wanted to **make this** [image: Present Magento Menu] **to
this in my custom theme**
[image: My wanted Magento Menu].
So now in **topmenu.php** of **Magento\Theme\Block\Html** I am afraid to change anything if I broke something. [image: Present Magento Menu Code][image]
how can I replace **This left-side code style**  with **This right-side code style** in **Topmenu.php**
I am not an expert in Magento so if I change something without knowing it could break anything. So if anyone expert could help me out to accomplish my goal. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of `CategoryFactory` you can get a collection of your categories, like so:

```
    public function getChildCategories($categoryId)
    {
        $category = $this->categoryFactory->create();
        $categoryCollection = $category->load($categoryId);

        //Get category collection
        return $categoryCollection->getCollection()
            ->addNavigationMaxDepthFilter()
            ->addUrlRewriteToResult()
            ->addIsActiveFilter()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', 1)
            ->addAttributeToSelect(['name', 'url'])
            ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
            ->addIdFilter($categoryCollection->getChildren());
    }
```

In your template you can then loop through the collection and build your mega menu.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do I need to add this code alongside the existent **Topmenu.php** or create a new **Topmenu.php**?